# ¿Cuál es la palabra para referirse al que hace apología?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, vocabulario

¿Cuál es la palabra para referirse a la persona que hace apología de algo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tal y como comenta Fundéu en [apologeta y apologista, uso adecuado](http://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/apologeta-apologista/):

> **Apologeta** y **apologista** se emplean hoy con el mismo sentido.
>
> Si bien el Diccionario panhispánico de dudas desaconsejaba el uso indistinto de apologista y apologeta con el significado de ‘que hace apología o defensa de algo’, la vigesimotercera edición del Diccionario académico ya incluye, sin censurarla, esta acepción para el segundo término.

Comment: Julio, buena respuesta. Lee [How to reference material written by others](/help/referencing) para futuras ocasiones en las que cites cosas escritas por otras personas, pues es necesario citar de forma explícita.